# Remove multiples of numbers out of a list - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an exercise in Python but I'm constantly stuck.

Exercise: **Write a program that adds all numbers from 2 to 10,000 to a list.Then remove the multiples of 2 (but not 2), multiples of 3 (but not 3), and so on, up to the multiples of 100. Print the remaining values.**

```
def main():
    _list_ = []
    for i in range(2, 10001):
        _list_.append(i)

    multiples = 0
    multiple = 2
    while multiples <= 10000:
        multiples += 2
        _list_.remove(multiples)
main()
```

This is only the solution for 2 but how do I do it for the others like 3,... and without removing 3, 4, 5,...?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Hello. You may want to get familiar with [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Read about converting a list to a set and back. http://www.learnpython.org/en/Sets

Comment: If we cut out this superfluous intermediate stuff with creating lists for every single step this looks pretty easy: `print([number for number in range(2, 10001) if all(number % value or value == number for value in range(2, 101))])` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is much simpler ways to get the same result(prime numbers < 10000)
but if you insist to use that code you can add a simple loop

```
def main():
    _list_ = []
    for i in range(2, 10001):
        _list_.append(i)

    k=0
    while k<10000-2:# n starts from 2
        n = _list_[k]
        multiple = 2*n
        while multiple <= 10000:
            multiple += n
            _list_.remove(multiple)
        k = k + 1
main()
```